# Как удалить атрибут «disabled» на неактивном элементе при нажатии на него?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Нужно сделать так:

```
inPut.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
inPut.ondbclick = function(){
    inPut.setAttribute("disabled", "false")
};
```

Но, так не выйдет, ибо я кликаю на отключённый input. Какие есть выходы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var inPut = document.querySelector('input');

inPut.setAttribute("readonly", "true");
// inPut.setAttribute("disabled", "true"); <--- Aren't firing Events

inPut.addEventListener("dblclick", function(){
    console.log('dbClick');  // debug...
    inPut.removeAttribute('readonly');
    inPut.focus();
});
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <input type="text" id="inp">
</div>
```

Comment: Найс. Без лишних референсов к телу документа.

Comment: @Bharata Просто у меня в скрипте и так дофига референсов к телу…

Answer (score 3):

Вот так можно сделать:

```js
var inPut = document.querySelector("input");
inPut.setAttribute("disabled", "true");

document.onclick = function(e)
{
 if(e.target == inPut)
 {
  inPut.removeAttribute("disabled");
  inPut.focus();
 }
 else
  inPut.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
};
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Если нажать на `input`, то он станет активным, а если мимо, то снова заблокированным.